# How to create view with angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, user-interface, view

Is there any way to simulate view creator method like kendo with angular?

```
var view = new kendo.View($("#id-of-element"));
view.render();
```

Comment: Please be more specific about what you are trying to accomplish. See [ask]

Comment: I want to showing some elements of a html file, i try to select that element first.

Comment: That is simply not specific enough and there are lots of ways to create different views in angular

Comment: So please suggest one of them.

Comment: using a router is  common. If you want help here you need to learn to be specific since this is a technical problem solving site and technical problems typically require details

Comment: Thanks for your advice.